# histograms with shaded lines bars ( no color bars )

Tags: gnuplot

I have a set of data to plot using histogram bars. I want the bars to be shaded in lines but not filled with colros like red, blue or any other colors. The sample data is as below:

```
1 23 2 9 13
2 25 5 7 12
3 26 5 3 13
4 20 6 8 5
5 23 5 12 15
6 23 5 12 11
7 22 9 12 5
8 24 16 5 8
9 23 2 12 10
10 23 15 5 9
```

I have the sample code as well,

```
 set terminal jpeg medium
 set output "histo.jpeg"
 set boxwidth 0.75 absolute
 set style fill solid 1.00 border -1
 set style histogram rowstacked
 set style data histograms
 set xtics 1000 nomirror
 set ytics 100 nomirror
 set mxtics 2
 set mytics 2
 set ytics 10
 set yrange [0:50]
 set ylabel "Total time"
 set xlabel "Session number"

 plot 'papa2.dat' using 3 t "Server", '' using 4 t "Client", '' using 5:xtic(1) t "Network"
```

But when I use this I get bars in histogram filled with colors.

Can anyone help me to on how to plot the graphs in lines instead of colors?
Many thanks in advance.

(note: I got these sample data and code from internet)

Answer (score 0):

I wonder what you want is something shown in the first figure of this page: [histograms.dem](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/histograms.html).

If that is the case, you can either do `set style data linespoint` as shown in the demo page, or `plot 'papa2.dat' using 3 t "Server" with line` when you use the plot command.

Note that you have a lot more demo scripts available in the gnuplot project website: [Demo scripts for gnuplot 4.4](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/)